# How to select scale x,y,z keyframes all at once in graph editor

Tags: animation, graph-editor

For a simple scaling animation, I am trying to change the bezier curve for all three dimensions at the same time. I know that I can box select the keyframe itself and move it with g, but I cannot figure out how to grab the handles for all three dimensions at the same time.

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

In the *Graph Editor*, on the right side you will see the sidebar that shows you all objects and items that have some animation attached to it. Select your object from that list and make sure to widen the drop menu of it beside its name. There you will see the different axis. Using <kbd>Shift</kbd> select all of the. Next in the actual editor press <kbd>A</kbd> once or twice so all handles are selected and then press <kbd>S</kbd> to scale all of them.

Answer (score -3):

To select all the keyframes, click Control+A.

Comment: ...It should be just "a".  You don't need Ctrl.